# Tensorflow input function returns invalid values (Tensor instead of Tensor dict)

Tags: python, dataframe, tensorflow, image-processing

I have been working on standard image classification problem with Tensorflow. Most of the code is derived from tutorials on www.tensorflow.org, the only major change is that I use my own data.

The images are already processed, of same size, encoding etc., and sorted into appropriate folders called groupA and groupB. While most of the code worked without a problem (images get loaded from disk and decoded, labels are assigned etc.) I encountered an unexpected roadblock.

```
labels = tf.constant([1.0 if 'groupA' in filename else 0.1 for filename in training_data])

file_names = tf.constant(training_data)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((file_names, labels))

  def _parse_function(filename, label):

      image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
      image = tf.image.decode_png(filename)
      return image, label

dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)

def create_input_fn_train(dataset):
    def input_fn():
        ds = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
        ds = ds.batch(16)
        ds = ds.repeat()

        iterator = ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
        images, labels = iterator.get_next()

        return images, labels
    return input_fn

input_fn_train = create_input_fn_train(dataset)
model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=[construct_feature_columns(150,150)],
                        hidden_units=[1024,100],
                        optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4),
                        n_classes=2,
                        dropout=0.1,
                        model_dir="./tmp/fon_model")
```

The input function is returning wrong type of data, causing following error.

```
ValueError("features should be a dictionary of `Tensor`s. Given type: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>",)
```

I tried to look up possible solutions, leading me to [tensorflow ValueError: features should be a dictionary of `Tensor`s. Given type: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49209810/tensorflow-valueerror-features-should-be-a-dictionary-of-tensors-given-type) and tried the provided solution.

```
def _parse_function(filename, label):

        image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
        image = tf.image.decode_png(filename)
        features = {}
        features['pixels'] = image
        return features, label
```

But it gave me another error message, this time:

```
ValueError("Items of feature_columns must be a _FeatureColumn. Given (type <class 'set'>): {_NumericColumn(key='pixels', shape=(22500,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None)}.",)
```

Which leads me to believe that I made some sort of fundamental error. Either when parsing the data, assigning labels etc.

But I can't figure out where I went wrong.

**EDIT:**

I altered the code so that estimator constructor is

```
model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=construct_feature_columns(150,150),
                    hidden_units=[1024,100],
                    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4),
                    n_classes=2,
                    dropout=0.1,
                    model_dir="./tmp/fon_model")
```

and the *construct_feature_columns* into:

```
def construct_feature_columns(image_height, image_width):
    return set([tf.feature_column.numeric_column('pixels', shape=[image_height*image_width])])
```

Eliminating the ValueError:

```
ValueError("Items of feature_columns must be a _FeatureColumn. Given (type <class 'set'>): {_NumericColumn(key='pixels', shape=(22500,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None)}.",)
```

I also rewrote the input function into:

```
def input_fn():
        ds = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=len(training_data))
        ds = ds.batch(16)
        ds = ds.repeat()

        iterator = ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
        images, labels = iterator.get_next()
        images = {'pixels':images}
        return images, labels
```

However new error turned up, confirming my belief that I messed up something fundamental:

```
UnimplementedError (see above for traceback): Cast string to float is not supported
     [[Node: dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_layer/pixels/ToFloat = Cast[DstT=DT_FLOAT, SrcT=DT_STRING, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_layer/pixels/ExpandDims)]]
```